# Why are wicked_pdf asset helpers generating errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf in a Rails 4.1 app.

PDF generation works perfectly within my local dev setup. But I get errors when deployed to Heroku.

Checking the logs I see

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory - /app/public/photos/application.js):
```

associated with the wicked_pdf helpers

```
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

1. I understood that the wicked_pdf helpers generated absolute urls, so
   why am I seeing a relate url originating from the app folder?
2. How is this path being generated? I have no public/photos folder in
   my app!
3. How do I go about debugging this problem? I'm unsure if this is a Heroku issue, a wkhtmltopdf issue, an asset compilation issue, or...?

Is anyone using wicked_pdf successfully on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

This is a new issue in Rails 4 (4.1?), where the compiled assets come out with digests like this:

application-4dd5b109ee3439da54f5bdfd78a80473.js

but no plain

application.js

is generated anymore.

You can try this gem https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets

or I would recommend base64 encoding your assets like described in this issue:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/257

I'm working on rolling this into `WickedPdf` very soon, as this is a common issue to have differences in environments due to asset pipeline stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I see that there is no an asets digest in log info that rails use for assets in producation environment.
I think the gem should resolve the issue because it was written for using wikedpdf on Heroku.
You can add it like that:

```
group :production do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku"
end
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Tunaki I've rewrited my answer and removed link to the gem.